# Commercially available conductive polymers

Tags: polymers, conductivity, plastics

I am looking for intrinsically conductive plastics (not plastics that are made conductive by filling them with carbon black for example). I have found that there are conductive polymers like polyanilin, polythiophene and polypyrrole that are sometimes used as conductive coatings. But are any of these materials commercially availabe as sheet material? As it is the case with conductive PE UHMW for example? I am looking for sheets with a thickness of about 5 mm that I can machine into different shapes.

Additional question: Does anyone know if there are any commercially available metal / polymer composites?

Comment: There are many plastic sheet stock suppliers that provide 'conductive' material. Often they mean it does not build up static charge. How conductive do you mean by conductive?

Comment: Yes, i know, but as I understood these materials are made conductive by mixing them with carbon black which is not what I am looking for. A surface resistance somewhere below 10^6 ohms is sufficient.

Comment: So, something like "Semitron ESd 410C
Standard Sheet Size: 12" x 12"
The Semitron ESd products are inherently dissipative and do not rely on atmospheric phenomena (e.g. humidity) to activate, nor are surface treatments used to achieve dissipation.
Does not contain carbon or graphite powder to provide electrostatic dissipation, sloughing is not a problem."

Comment: Yes exactily, thank you! Can you send me a link where you found this text? I find the material but not this exact description of it.

Comment: Googling 'Semitron ESd' will bring up the links of Alro and their many suppliers. Multiple grades, you will need to select what might be best.